# Heroku Integration with Intellij

Tags: java, git, heroku, intellij-idea

I am looking for Heroku Integration plugin for Intellij community
There is old one but it does not work new ver intelij
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6659

here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/getting-started-with-heroku.html#d250812e36
they say that:

> Making sure that Heroku and Git Integration plugins are enabled
>
> To be able to work with Heroku and Git on Heroku, the Heroku
>   Integration and the Git Integration plugins must be enabled. To make
>   sure that these plugins are enabled, use the Plugins page of the
>   Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S | Plugins).

But I could not find plugin.

Comment: The linked Help page describes functionality available only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. There is no JetBrains-supported Heroku plugin for Community Edition.

Comment: Check first link, Heroku integration for all Jetbrains products.Compatible with:  IntelliJ IDEA, Android Studio

Comment: This is not a JetBrains-supported plugin.